# Getting error when a user is not logged in because Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')` can not check if the user has role of admin in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an a tag that works as a delete button for an image, however, in my blade template I display the button only to the uploader of the image or the admins of the website. Unfortunately, when a user is not logged, I get an error because `Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')` can not check if the user has role of admin. Any idea how am I supposed to avoid this problem?

The error:

```
"Call to a member function hasRole() on null"
```

My code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='imageContainer'>
        <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
        <div class="stickyImageContainer">
            <img class='uploadedRealImage' src='/storage/images/uploaded/{{$image->file_name}}' alt='Random image'/>
            @if (Auth::id() === $image->user_id || Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
                <div class='deleteImageButton'></div>
                <a class='deleteImageA' href='{{ route('deleteImage', ['image_id' => $image->id]) }}'>X</a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `Auth::user()` returned a model or just `null` first:

```
@if (Auth::id() === $image->user_id || (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')))
```

It's probably cleaner to break these into two nested :

```
@if(Auth::user())
    @if(Auth::id() === $image->user_id || Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
```

or even better, use [Laravel's authorization gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) to encompass this logic, which will allow you to do:

```
@can('delete', $image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `auth()->check()` prior to attempting to access the user's role.

```
@if(auth()->check()  && Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
    ....
@endif
```

Laravel also offers the `can` and `cannot` blade directives. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates